# Unity modular NPC

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, fbx, 3d-modelling

We are developing a Top Down RPG Game. So, there's a question about NPCs. Making a lot of NPC FBX files would not be optimal. From what I know, people usually make 3-4 bodies and a bunch of heads, so the NPCs would look different. Do you guys have any idea, if there's an optimal way of doing that?

I tried modelling bodies and heads in separate files and then putting heads onto the empty object on top of the body (this empty object was part of the FBX itself). It didn't work, as the actual head always displayed too high above, so it looked like the head was hovering in the air.

I also thought about making heads a part of one big FBX with just one body. So all the head would be on the same coordinate in space, and so in Unity there would be a possibility of making active just one head in time. I still don't think it would be very optimal.

So, is there a way people usually do this? I mean, this must be really common. They used it in Gothic, for sure and in many other games. So there must be an optimal way, but I'm unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few character customization packages available on asset store that you could use. I recommend UMA2 (Unity Multipurpose Avatar). It is a perfect tool and I'm using it on one of my projects and it's really gets the job done. And the good thing is that it's free. Once you imported it into your project, you can either buy contents (cloth, hair, face, ...) or create your own contents like I do using blender. There are tutorials about how to integrate and create contents on Secret Anorak youtube channel.